# Find value matching value in a list of dicts

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts that looks like this:

```
serv=[{'scheme': 'urn:x-esri:specification:ServiceType:DAP',
  'url': 'http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/air.mon.anom.nobs.nc'},
 {'scheme': 'urn:x-esri:specification:ServiceType:WMS',
  'url': 'http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/wms/Datasets/air.mon.anom.nobs.nc?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities'},
 {'scheme': 'urn:x-esri:specification:ServiceType:WCS',
  'url': 'http://ferret.pmel.noaa.gov/geoide/wcs/Datasets/air.mon.anom.nobs.nc?service=WCS&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities'}]
```

and I want to find the URL corresponding to the `ServiceType:WMS` which means finding the value of `url` key in the dictionary from this list where the `scheme` key has value `urn:x-esri:specification:ServiceType:WMS`.

So I've got this that works:

```
for d in serv:
    if d['scheme']=='urn:x-esri:specification:ServiceType:WMS':
        url=d['url']
print url
```

which produces

```
http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/wms/Datasets/air.mon.anom.nobs.nc?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities
```

but I've just watched [Raymond Hettinger's PyCon talk](https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/transforming-code-into-beautiful-idiomatic-python-by-raymond-hettinger) and at the end he says that that if you can say it as a sentence, it should be expressed in one line of Python.

So is there a more beautiful, idiomatic way of achieving the same result, perhaps with one line of Python?

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `serv` array you listed looks like a dictionary mapping schemes to URLs, but it's not represented as such. You can easily convert it to a `dict` using list comprehensions, though, and then use normal dictionary lookups:

```
url = dict([(d['scheme'],d['url']) for d in serv])['urn:x-esri:specification:ServiceType:WMS']
```

You can, of course, save the dictionary version for future use (at the cost of using two lines):

```
servdict = dict([(d['scheme'],d['url']) for d in serv])
url = servdict['urn:x-esri:specification:ServiceType:WMS']
```

Comment: You are completely right -- this list of dicts really should be a single dict matching service type with URL.  Although the answers provided by others are more generally applicable, for this specific case, this is the answer I'm going to go with in my code.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in one URL, then you can build a generator over `serv` and use `next` with a default value for the cases where a match isn't found, eg:

```
url = next((dct['url'] for dct in serv if dct['scheme'] == 'urn:x-esri:specification:ServiceType:WMS'), 'default URL / not found')
```

Comment: This is cool because it anticipates the problem where the serviceType I'm looking for is not in the list. I think this is the best general answer, although for my specific case I'm going with Nikita's solution of turning my list of dicts into a single dict.

Comment: It also represents the best expression of what Hettinger was suggesting in that you can read it from left to right like this sentence: "iterate until you find the url where the scheme matches a specific string, otherwise use default".

Answer (score 2):

I would split this into two lines, to separate the target from the url retrieval.  This is because your target may change in time, so this should not be hardwired.  The single line of code follows.

I would use `in` instead of `==` as we want to search for all schemes that are of this type.  This adds more flexibility, and readability, assuming this will not also catch other schemes not wanted.  But from the description, this is the functionality desired.

```
target = "ServiceType:WMS"
url = [d['url'] for d in serv if target in d['scheme']]
```

Also, note, this returns a list in all cases, in case there is more than one match, so you will have to loop over `url` in the code that uses this.

Comment: I like the use of ```in``` instead of ```==```.  Good tip!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
urls = [d['url'] for d in serv if d['scheme'] == 'urn:x-esri:specification:ServiceType:WMS']

print urls # ['http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/wms/Datasets/air.mon.anom.nobs.nc?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities']
```

Its doing the same thing your code is doing, where `d['url']` are being appended to the list - `urls` if they end with `WMS`

You can even add an else clause:

```
urls = [i['url'] for i in serv if i['scheme'].endswith('WMS') else pass]
```

Comment: I like this answer because it shows me in general how to convert my logic into a one-liner. Cool.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to work in more functional programming into my own work, so here is a pretty simple functional way:

```
needle='urn:x-esri:specification:ServiceType:WMS'
url = filter( lambda d: d['scheme']==needle, serv )[0]['url']
```

`filter` takes as arguments a function that returns a boolean and a list to be filtered.  It returns a list of elements that return `True` when passed to the boolean-returning function (in this case a `lambda` I defined on the fly).  So, to finally get the url, we have to take the zeroth element of the list that `filter` returns. Since that is the dict containing our desired url, we can tag `['url']` on the end of the whole expression to get the corresponding dictionary entry.

Comment: Nice - I can see the power of using that test function for more complex cases.